# Magento 2.2.9 - Problem with one product attribute

Tags: magento2.2, product-attribute, magento2.2.9

I have one problem when i want to Save some changes in product page in Admin Page

`(Catalog->Inventory->Products->One of the products, configurable or simple)`.

One of the attributes, in this case this is length (which parameters you see) is causing some problems when i add it to the Attribute Set (whichever).

[image: length-attribute with problem, lengthtest-good attribute]

Normally when I save changes in product attributes, all of the changes are applied. But when list of attributes has got 'length', when i write new value to the whichever attribute, or check the checkbox with "Use default value", and hit Save, page refreshes and nothing is saved. All attributes go to values that they have before the save. 
One thing that i saw, when i was debugging this problem is that, the $data variable which i've got from

`$this->getRequest()->getPostValue();`

has got `use_default` array which is changing when i want to save attributes. But when there is no `lenght` attribute this array is full of informations.

[image]

But when I add `length' to the list of attributes, this array has got only one word which is "".
[image]

So there is problem somewhere but i can't find him. I am new to Magento and i don't everything about product attributes. 
And one more information about this problem is that i make new attribute that has the same options checked and this attribute is working good and making no problems when i save product changes.